# Method to select specific date interval in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, filter

I have a large table one of the columns contains datetime vector, in the format **(uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)**.
Assuming that the datetime vector is from 2020-01-01 till 2020-12-31

I am trying to select from the datetime vector specific date, e.g. from **2020-02-04 00:00:00** till **2020-03-16 00:00:00** and extract the table corresponding from the date specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use logical indexing and a condition on your datetime variable like so

```
filterFrom = datetime( 2020, 2, 4 ); % 2020-02-04 00:00:00
filterTo = datetime( 2020, 3, 16 );  % 2020-03-16 00:00:00

% Variable "tbl" contains your data, with a datetime variable DatetimeVar
tblFiltered = tbl( tbl.DatetimeVar >= filterFrom & tbl.DatetimeVar <= filterTo, : );
```